# What has 58 hearts?

Tags: riddle

This is a short puzzle.

Each of us has a heart.

Zaphod Beeblebrox may have two heads and three arms, but only had one heart.

Dr Who famously was reputed to have two hearts.

Squid have three hearts and Hag Fish four, but what has 58 hearts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a potential answer:

> A standard deck of cards, using the hearts suit. 1 + 2 + ... + 10 = 55, then three more for each of the three face cards. The actual number of heart symbols shown in a deck of cards might vary. Two of the diagonally opposing corners of a card usually also carry the suit, and face cards tend to have four of the symbol. So this might not give 58 hearts in a real-life deck, but perhaps in an idealized one.

Comment: Excellent - spot on - as I said in the question it is a 'short puzzle'

Answer (score 2):

What has 58 hearts?

> 29 Timelords.

Comment: Or maybe rot13(Fabj Juvgr naq gur 57 qjnesf)?

Comment: :-)     :-)    :-) plus one for nice answer